# Trying to install Kali Linux without Usb/Dvd

Tags: linux, windows, installation

I tried to install kali linux on windows without usb/dvd using unetbootin which was installed to the drive (C:). but it always fails to detect and mount the cd-rom.

so i tried to install linux mint using unetbootin to drive (C:) without usb/dvd, everything went smoothly.

does anyone know how to skip or fix mount and detect cd-rom on a kali linux installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Execute a shell and Click Continue Button Type the following command on the shell screen that appears

mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /cdrom

exit

Comment: I've done using command on the shell but still not detected. I install kali linux using unetbootin to hdd (C:) I've also tried ntfs and exfat format but still stuck on mount and detecting cd-rom.